# Filter files with specific substring in name LINQ

Tags: linq

I have list of files in a directory that I want to filter. The file names are like:

```
FileBanana.txt
FileMango.txt
FileBananaShake.txt
FileOrange.txt
FileGrapes.txt
FileOrangeJuice.txt
FileNactarine.txt
```

I would like to get a **List of String** with files which contain any of items in another List {"Orange", "Banana"}

How can I do that using LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried it for just one filename? Get that working, and then it will be easy to extend it to a list of filenames.

Comment: I tried with result = from p in filenames
           where filter.Any(val => p.Contains(val))
           select p; but this will only search if filter i.e. orange or banana is contains completes filename but not substring. Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: There are lots of answers on the web for linq queries of files.  Please clarify what you're trying to do?  -- So you don't really have FILES, you really just have a list of strings (that happen to look like filenames)?

Comment: @user869375 That query should do exactly what you're looking for. What goes wrong when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just confused myself. This worked just fine:

```
List<string> stringFiles = new List<string>() {"FileBanana.txt", "FileMango.txt", "FileBananaShake.txt", "FileOrange.txt", "FileGrapes.txt", "FileOrangeJuice.txt", "FileGrapes.txt" };

List<string> filterKeywords = new List<string>() { "Orange", "Banana" };

var result = from p in stringFiles
                 where filterKeywords.Any(val => p.Contains(val))
                 select p;
```

Comment: That query will give you an `IEnumerable<string>`, so you need to put a `.ToList()` on it, like `var result = stringFiles.Where(t => filterKeywords.Any(x => t.IndexOf(x) >= 0)).ToList();`. If you use `IndexOf` you have the option of using an overload to make it case-insensitive.